# Jquery mobile duplicate images

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi i have a problem with my jquery mobile application, when i visit a page and got back to the home page and visit again some items are duplicated.  Each time i visit my page again the items are progressively duplicated.

it looks as though there is some kind of cache going on.

my code is as follows, any help would be much appreciated.

I am using version 1.3.0 of jquery mobile but this also happens on version 1.2.0

How do i clear the cache or remove the page from the cache?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Bucuresti Deals</title> 
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">

.ui-header.ui-bar-a{
background-color: white;
}

.ui-header .ui-title {
text-indent:-9999px;
font-size:0px;
background:url(../images/headerbar.png) no-repeat 50% 2px;
height:30px;
padding:5px 0 5px 50px;
margin:0px;
}


img { 
   border:1px solid black;

   margin-left: 10px;

}

#mainTable
{
border:2px solid;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:25px; /* Old Firefox */
width:100%;

}

th
{
height:10px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
} 

#detail{
    vertical-align:top;
}



.ui-corner-all,

.ui-corner-top,

.ui-corner-bottom,

.ui-corner-tl,

.ui-corner-tr,

.ui-corner-bl,

.ui-header .ui-btn-corner-all,

.ui-listview-filter .ui-btn-corner-all,

#restau_infos .ui-btn-corner-all,

#contact_buttons .ui-btn-corner-all,

#notation .ui-btn-corner-all{

border-radius:0.2em;

}
</style>

</head> 
<body> 

<div id="restaurant_detail" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-theme="c">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c"> 
        <h1> Restaurant Information</h1>
        <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
    </div> 

    <div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a" id="restau_info">    
        <div class="ui-block-a" >
        <h1 id="name"></h1>
        <p id="title"></p>
        <p> Specials: </p>
            <ul id="specials"> 
                <li id='special1'></li>
                <li id='special2'></li>
                <li id='special3'></li>
                <li id='special4'></li>
                <li id='special5'></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>      
        <div class="ui-block-b" id="infoBlock">
         <p><a id="website" href="#" rel="external" data-role="button"> See our website</a></p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /grid-a -->
    <hr/>

    <div class="ui-grid-a" id="contact_infos">  
        <div class="ui-block-a">
        <h2 id="contactus"> Contact us</h2>     
        </div>      
        <div class="ui-block-b">
        <img src="01_maps.jpg" alt="plan jeanette"/>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /grid-a -->
    <div id="contact_buttons">  
        <a href="#" id="telephone" data-role="button" data-icon="tel"> Call us </a> 
    </div>  
    <hr/>

    <div id="notation"> 
    <form>
    <label for="select-choice-0" class="select"><h2> User rating </h2></label>
        <select name="note_utilisateur" id="note_utilisateur" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="c" >
           <option value="one" class="one"> Not good at all </option>
           <option value="two" class="two">Average </option>
           <option value="three" class="three">Pretty good </option>
           <option value="four" class="four"> Excellent </option>
        </select>   
    </form>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( '#restaurant_detail' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){

        // get the establishment id from session data
        var est_id = sessionStorage.estID;

        var pass_url = "http:/MySite/getRestaurantDetail.php?est_id=" + est_id;

        // Call ajax to get the restaurants in the area

        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:pass_url,
            dataType:'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status)
            { 
              $.each(data, function(i,item)
              {


                // Set the name of the restaurant
                $("#name").text(item.rest_name);

                // Set the title for restaurant
                $("#title").html('<strong>' + item.rest_title + '</strong>');

                // Specials
                $("#special1").text(item.rest_special1);
                $("#special2").text(item.rest_special2);
                $("#special3").text(item.rest_special3);
                $("#special4").text(item.rest_special4); 
                $("#special5").text(item.rest_special5); 

                $('#specials li:empty').remove();

                // Address line 1 and 2
                $("<p id='address1'>" + item.rest_address1 + "</p>").insertAfter('#contactus');

                // photo

                $('#infoBlock').prepend("<p id='photo'><img src='http://MySite/" + item.rest_photo_url + "' alt=" + item.rest_name + "/></p>");

                // website address
                $("#website").attr('href',item.rest_web_url);
                $("#webiste").css('width','20px');


                // telephone number
                $("#telephone").attr('href', item.rest_tel);

                // apply css style to span with the class of ui-icon-tel
                $(".ui-icon-tel").css("background","url('../images/phone_icon.png') no-repeat");


             });        
            },
            error: function(data)
            {

            }
        });

        var SelectedOptionClass = $('option:selected').attr('class');
        $('div.ui-select').addClass(SelectedOptionClass);

        $('#note_utilisateur').live('change', function(){    
            $('div.ui-select').removeClass(SelectedOptionClass);

            SelectedOptionClass = $('option:selected').attr('class');
            $('div.ui-select').addClass(SelectedOptionClass);       

        });

    });




</script>


    </div>


</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

PHP server side code

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$est_id = $_GET['est_id'];

$server = "server";
$username = "username";
$password = "pass";
$database = "database";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);


$sql = 'SELECT establishments.establishment_id AS estID, 
        name AS rest_name, 
        title AS rest_title,
        special_1 AS rest_special1,
        special_2 AS rest_special2,
        special_3 AS rest_special3,
        special_4 AS rest_special4,
        special_5 AS rest_special5,
        website_address AS rest_web_url,
        address AS rest_address1,
        telephone_num AS rest_tel,
        description AS rest_desc, 
        photo_url AS rest_photo_url 
     FROM bucurestideals1.establishments
     WHERE establishments.establishment_id  ="'.$est_id.'"';

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

I was able to resolve this by
1. Changing the function from .live to .on and also returning false at the end of the executed function i.e.

```
// apply css style to span with the class of ui-icon-tel
                $(".ui-icon-tel").css("background","url('../images/phone_icon.png') no-repeat");


             });
            return false;
            },
            error: function(data)
            {

            }

        });
```

Comment: There must be something going on with you cache. I tried and refresh numerous times and cannot reproduce your scenario. Here is the JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/gte6F/ try it there and see if you get it.

Comment: The data for the app comes from the a database so it may not work the same

Comment: What server side programming language are you using?

Comment: php, ill add my server side code to the above original question

Comment: Perfect, that will definitely help.

Comment: I edited and removed your server information. Be careful when posting code not to post database servers and passwords :)

Comment: Thank you, i just realized that myself just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that every time you visit a page you are appending data to whatever already is in the DOM with the `prepend()` method. I would suggest you clear the elements (`infoBlock` div) you append data to before you append data on them, or in other words, on the `live()` event.

Comment: do you me something like $("#infoBlock").empty();

Comment: Something like $("#infoBlock").html(""); .empty() would leave the children inside infoBlock (http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: unfortunately still no luck i'll have a closer luck in the morning. Thank you so far for you advice

Comment: For you information i looked at this in firebug and i can see that when visiting the page the ajax call to the php is executed twice when you visit the page for the second time

Comment: I was able to resolve this by 1. Changing the function from .live to .on and also returning false at the end of the executed function i.e.

// apply css style to span with the class of ui-icon-tel
                $(".ui-icon-tel").css("background","url('../images/phone_icon.png') no-repeat");


             });
            return false;
            },
            error: function(data)
            {

            }

        });

Comment: Oh!  I am so glad you were able to figure it out! I was about to tell you the live function was deprecated, but I forgot.